# How can I make a transition to a linear model?

Tags: r, ggplot2

From a database called "datoschile" that incorporates 6 variables, I have created a panel data called "magrupados3" that uses the variable "Periodo" as an identity variable and I have filtered th**strong text**e information using only "Importaciones" and "Exportaciones" variables

This the excel file needed to work with this code

https://gitlab.com/pedritoandrade/how-can-i-make-a-transition-to-a-linear-model

```
datos <- read.xlsx("C:\\Users\\PEDRO ANDRADE 2019\\Desktop\\Curso Betametrica\\Analisis exploratorio y automatizacion de reportes\\datoschile.xlsx",
                   sheet = "Hoja1",
                   detectDates = T)`

magrupados3 <- melt(datos, id.vars = "Periodo")%>%
  filter(variable == "Exportaciones" | variable == "Importaciones")`
```

Then with this data, I have created a graph using geom_line and geom_point and also the tendency line using geom_smooth. This is the code and the result you can see it here:

```
magrupados4 <- ggplot(data=magrupados3,aes(x=Periodo,y=value))+
geom_line()+geom_point()+facet_wrap(variable~.,scales = "free",ncol = 2)+
geom_smooth(method = "lm",formula= y~x,col="black",se=F)`
```

Graph

[image]

I want to make a transition of this graph. In other words, I want that geom_line and the regression line (geom_smooth) to appear simultaneously each year(my variable that represents year in my data is called "Periodo").
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please review how to create a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example

Comment: Are you looking to make an animation, eg using gganimate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to use the R package ***gganimate*** in combination with the R packages: ***devtools***, ***ggplot2***, ***gifski***, and ***av***.

Check this link: https://gganimate.com/

[image]

Here is an example that I took from that website. It is working in my computer. You need the libraries that are in my example. ***Some libraries were not in the website example. Be careful with that. In your code, you did not use the last two lines of this example*** (transition_time(year) + ease_aes('linear')). ***Also, I guess that you did not install all the R libraries that are needed.***

```
# install.packages('devtools')
# devtools::install_github('thomasp85/gganimate')
library(devtools)
library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(gifski)
library(av)

ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, colour = country)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.7, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = country_colors) +
  scale_size(range = c(2, 12)) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  facet_wrap(~continent) + labs(title = 'Year: {frame_time}', x = 'GDP per capita', y = 'life expectancy')+
  transition_time(year) +
  ease_aes('linear')
```